Tesseract.js worker script fails to load from local copy in Chrome extension
I'm developing a Chrome extension that utilizes Tesseract.js for OCR functionality. I've configured Webpack to include the Tesseract.js worker script (worker.min.js) from the local copy in the bundled extension files. However, when testing the extension, I encounter the error
"Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tesseract.js@v5.1.0/dist/worker.min.js' failed to load."

I've verified that the worker script is correctly included in the bundled files, and I've checked the generated HTML files to ensure they reference the local copy. Additionally, I've inspected the Content Security Policy (CSP) and cleared the browser cache, but the issue persists.
I suspect there might be an issue with how the Chrome extension is loading the worker script or with the CSP settings. How can I ensure that the Chrome extension loads the Tesseract.js worker script from the local copy instead of attempting to fetch it from the CDN?
Here's a simplified version of my Webpack configuration:

  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: path.resolve('src/static'), to: path.resolve('dist') },
        { from: path.resolve('node_modules/tesseract.js/dist/worker.min.js'), to: path.resolve('dist') },
        { from: path.resolve('node_modules/tesseract.js/dist/tesseract.min.js'), to: path.resolve('dist') }
      ],
    }),
 


Debug it by inspecting the final output js code and check what path is used in importScripts and where it comes from.
